# What are the top browsers to test on?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, manual-testing, test-management, cross-browser-testing

I have made a web platform for the cab booking service. And I want to ensure the user interface and functionality of my web application is working across different browsers.

But there are many browsers available in the market, can you people suggest me to choose the browsers for testing?

Answer (score 3):

You can search around for browser statistics over the Internet. As an example here is the stats provided by [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/Browsers/default.asp) based on over 45 million monthly visits.

***NB!*** The table captions are clickable so that you can drill into the details of particular browser version stats.

Comment: Be careful, that data for w3schools.com is for the visitors of w3schools.com.  Your actual customer behavior might vary from the that particular site.  You should add an analytics package, like Google Analytics, to tell you the browser from your customer set.  It does vary based on a number of factors like technical acumen of the users, geography, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You would know in which region your app will be providing services or targeting customers. You can use this http://gs.statcounter.com/ to find list of browser share as per region.

We also use this in our software testing company. As per stats worldwide usage of web browsers for August 2017
Chrome : 54.89% 
Safari : 14.88%
UC Browser : 7.43%
Firefox : 5.9%
Opera : 4%
IE : 3.69%

Note: You should also check for mobile browsers also if you have a mobile app also.