# How do enterprises test their web apps across all browsers, browser versions, and operating systems?

Tags: manual-testing, cross-browser-testing

There are various websites which work perfectly on all the platforms and OS.  I want to know how they test their possibilities for every combination?

Comment: Please add more detail about how the answers you got to the question you asked that Alexey R linked didn't answer the question you have now. You have a history of asking almost the same question over and over again (also [What are the top browsers to test on?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29370/what-are-the-top-browsers-to-test-on)) which is bad etiquette and will discourage people from taking the time to give you good answers.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that

- They don't test on all of the combinations
- They focus on the ones that are used the most

For example there are literally thousands of Android devices and sizes and OS versions.  So no company is testing ALL of them.  Similarly, companies may agonize over testing ie6 vs ie7 vs i8 vs i9 is 2017 but none that I can imagine are still testing IE3 or early netscape versions.

So at the end of the day it comes down to value.  If you have 23,000 customers and $45.6 million in revenue per year and you can see that only 0.00023% of customers are using a version, that means only $105 of revenue and 1 customer is at stake.  Probably not a high priority compared to a similar sized change that will raise revenue by 0.04% = $18,240

Answer (score 2):

use BitBar or SauceLabs - companies specialized on providing hosting services for many devices/browsers/OS.

https://www.google.com/search?q=cross+browser+testing